# Gutenberg - detecting changes to post featured image alt_text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm working on a plugin for Gutenberg. My plugin has to access the alt_text attribute of the post's featured image to search for a keyword in it.
I access the featured image data like this:

```
const featuredId = select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media');
const featuredMedia = featuredId ? select('core').getMedia(featuredId) : null;
console.log(featuredMedia.alt_text || 'no media');
```

When I load the editor, everything works as expected. But if I do any changes to the featured image (edit alt text, replace or remove the image) and run the scritpt afterwards, I get the unchanged data of the featured image. No errors or warnings. Doesn't matter if I execute the code from my js files or the browser's console.
When I try editing the featured image once more I see changes in the Media Library, which is OK. The changes I made are available to JS after I save the edited post and refresh the page.
How can I access the updated featured image earlier (right after I click "Set featured image" button)? Or is it a bug in WordPress/Gutenberg? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The default context for `getMedia()` is **view** which does not return a value for alt_text. To return the alt_text immediately after a featured image is set, change the context to **embed**:

```
const featuredId = select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media');
const featuredMedia = featuredId ? select('core').getMedia(featuredId, { context: 'embed' }) : null;
console.log(featuredMedia.alt_text || 'no media');
```

The function `getMedia()` calls the [Media REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/) with any accepted parameters and returns the result. The context **embed** includes the `alt_text` in the response for images that aren't displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make any change. The alt_text field has been in the response before, but its value was not updated after editing the image's alt

Comment: @mpdoctor Can you confirm which version of the Gutenberg plugin you are testing with? I'm using 11.7.1 at present, though it was updated 6 days ago. The other thought I had is that some updates are batched now and don't happen instantly like they use to (in prior versions) and if you manually trigger a save event, it should force an update.

Comment: I'm not using the Gutenberg plugin, but I'm working with the latest version of WordPress and I'm writing a plugin that I'd like to notice changes to post featured image before the editor page is refreshed.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that my plugin reacts to changes to the alt text of the featured image and examines the new alt text searching for keywords in it (the keywords are provided by the user in a special form, but that's irrelevant), therefore I want it to run a certain function as soon as the user closes the Media Library confirming changes the have done.

Comment: @mpdoctor I've had another look at this and my thoughts is that given now changes and saves are being 'batched' in redux (which changed ~ May 2021) could be why you don't see the changed data immediately. Try forcing the data to update by manually triggering save post and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for the check, can you tell me how do I trigger save manually?